# How do I send an automated reply as soon as I receive an iMessage between a time frame on a MacBook?

Tags: macbook-pro, messages, automator

I have a MacBook, and I need to have a way to send an **automated reply** to all iMessages when I'm at work or doing a certain activity. For example, when I'm working, I want a message that could say something like "Hey, I'm busy. Will come back to you later when I'm done." to **automatically** be sent. Is this possible? I need it hugely, because I receive a lot of messages from friends and family while I'm working, and I can't respond to them. So I need the laptop to send them **automatically**.

Comment: Have you tried the [Do Not Disturb](https://support.apple.com/guide/mac-help/use-do-not-disturb-mchl999b7c1a/11.0/mac/11.0) feature built into macOS from Mojave and later versions? It should be capable of shielding you from seeing messages, but it has no feature to provide auto-replies.

Comment: The ability to auto-reply to messages in **macOS** was removed many years ago.

Comment: @IconDaemon I know about Do Not Disturb but I need to send auto replies.

Comment: @user3439894 I know that, but are there any third party apps that do that?

Comment: I've been unable to find a third-party auto-reply app which can do what you need.